# How to access a related object's field

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to store the campus that the teacher is associated with in the device model.  I tried creating a model method but was unable to access it from the related model.

```
class Campus(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Teacher(models.Model):
    campus = models.OneToOneField(Campus, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="Not Assigned")

class Device(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Do you want to store in it Device or be able to query to get it? it looks like you should be able to chain together in a filter(campus__teacher__device="android") sort of thing in a query, or use something similar on the save if you you really want to store it. Can you provide some more detail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your foreign key and one to one field, the queries you want would look like

```
device_queryset = Device.objects.all()

for device in device_queryset:
    print(device.owner.campus.name)
```

On an instance of Device, you can access the teacher model by referencing the field `owner`, which is a foreign key to `Teacher`. Once you are on `Teacher`, you can access its attributes like `campus`, and so on.

You may find the documentation on field lookups useful https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#id4